# Multivariate Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, predictive-models

I need a help to improve a formula for a probability model seeming to be multivariate bernoulli distribution.
What I have to build the model :

I have a learning base of documents $\{d_1,d_2,...,d_n\}$, and for each of them I know their class $k \in \{1,...,K\}$ (for instance sports, politics ...), and a set of words appearing in each document, so I can represent a given document $d_i$ as a vector of variables $d_i=(present_{d_i,1},...,present_{d_i,V}\} \in \{0,1\}^V$, with $\cal{V}$$=\{1,...,V\}$ my vocabulary.

**The goal is to build a model able, given a new document, to predict its class.**

**My model so far :** 
For each class $k$, for each word $w$, I calculate $P(w|k) = \frac{occurences\ of\ w\ in\ the\ documents\ of\ class\ k}{sum\ of\ occurences\ of\ all\ words\ in\ docs\ of\ class\ k}$ so that $\sum\limits_{w\in\cal{V}}p(w|k) = 1$.

For each class $k$, I calculate as well $p(k)=\frac{nb\ of\ docs\ of\ class\ k}{total\ nb\ of\ docs}$.

Then, given a document $d$, i calculate $argmax_{k\in\{1,..,K\}}(\prod\limits_{w\in\cal{V}}p(w|k)^{present(w,d)}(1-p(w|k)^{1-present(w,d)}$, where $present(w,d)$ equals one if $w$ is in $d$, 0 otherwise.

The results are not too bad, but far from being good as well, since with around 30 different classes of documents, my model predicts correctly the class in about 70% of cases.

**My question is : Do you have any idea on how to improve this model ?**

Useful thing : Even if I don't use them, I have at my disposal, for each document, not only the information 'is a word present or not?', but also the number of occurences a given word appears in a given document (I can count them), so my vector $d_i$ could actually be  $d_i=(N_{d_i,1},...,N_{d_i,V}\} \in \mathbb{N}^V$.

PS : This is my first question here, so I hope it's clear enough, if not, don't hesitate to tell me how to improve/modify it.

Comment: Have you tried just using a classifier (SVM, neural network, XGBOOST, etc) to predict the label, given your vector of variables?

Comment: No, I never heard of those, but i'm already reading about those. Thanks for the hint !